# How do I make a WHERE statement affect both an AND and OR variable?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**How do I make a WHERE statement affect both an AND and OR variable?**

- **For example this query is not recognizing both operators..**

`WHERE tableA.x = tableB.x
 AND tableA.y = 'abc'
 OR tableA.y = 'def'`

I'm not an SQL expert and I need to apply the `WHERE` statement above to both the `AND` and `OR` statements that succeed it. As it stands, it seems the `OR`statement discards the `WHERE` and executes as a separate entity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `x AND y OR z` is evaluated as `(x AND y) OR z`, which probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
'"Part #"',
'"Manu"',
'"Qty"',
'"Cost"',
'"Unit Qty"',
'"Received"',
'"partdesc"',
'"rohs status"',
'"Warehouse"',
'"row"',
'"rack"',
'"shelf"',
'"Position"'
UNION ALL (SELECT 
stmaster.partno,
stmaster.manuf,
stfifo.qty,
stfifo.cost,
stfifo.unitqty,
stfifo.datebookedin,
stmaster.partdesc,
stfifo.rohscompliance,
stfifo.warehouse,
stfifo.row,
stfifo.rack,
stfifo.shelf,
stfifo.positionfrom
FROM
    stfifo,
    stmaster
    WHERE stmaster.internal = stfifo.internal
        AND (stmaster.partno = '9300'
        OR stmaster.partno = '9508'))
```

Comment: I have edited my question to fit with Q&A format, you may wish to edit your answer. I require the rep on this particular SE site.

Comment: unbalanced parens.

Comment: The fields sizes are determined by the first `SELECT` in a `UNION`.  This will probably lead to some screwed up output.

Comment: This is only a snippet of my code. It runs fine now.